# Determine if NSImageView is highlighted

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsimageview

I have a view with multiple NSImageViews. How can I determine which NSImageView is highlighted when selected by the user? The `isHighlighted` property is always the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighted when selected by the user"? Are the image views in a container view, like a collection view or table view, and you're referring to whether they are selected? Or are they editable and have focus and show a focus ring?

Comment: I'm referring to the focus ring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine if any view has focus, you check if it is its window's `firstResponder`:

```
if (someView.window.firstResponder == someView)
    ...
```

There's a complication with text fields, because they use another object as a field editor, but that's not relevant for image views.